# Get Permalink (Current Page) With Share URL Is Not Working Properly

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use $facebookURL sharer php URL to avoid using the SDK.

Problem is it's grabbing the URL incorrectly. I'm not a coder.

Please see my code pen.

Q. Can someone advise on basics and what I'm doing wrong?

```
 setShareEvents = function() {
$(".myFacebookBtn").click(function() {
   var a = $(window).width() / 2 - 425,
        b = $(window).height() / 2 - 350,
        c = {
        url: $(this).attr("data-share-link")
        },
        c =facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?=" + $.param(c);
      window.open(
        c,
        "popupWindow",
        "width\x3d850,height\x3d700,scrollbars\x3dno, top\x3d" +
          b +
          ", left\x3d" +
          a
      );
      ga("send", "social", "facebook", "share", 
      $(this).attr("data-share-link")
      );
    });
```

[incorrect image snaphsot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzAfn.png)

You can [view my code pen](https://codepen.io/callmenicholi/pen/ayqOzy)

Q. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can see it working there :
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzdGLe)

```
 $(".myFacebookBtn").click(function() {

   var a = $(window).width() / 2 - 425,
        b = $(window).height() / 2 - 350,
        c = {
        u: $(this).attr("data-share-link")
        },
        c ="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?" + $.param(c);
      window.open(
        c,
        "popupWindow", "width\x3d850,height\x3d700,scrollbars\x3dno, top\x3d" +
          b +
          ", left\x3d" +
          a
      );
```

The parameters of the var 'c' need to be 'u' and not 'url'.

And you also need to add the data-share-link="http://somelink.com" in the li with the class 'myFacebookBtn' .

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: 1. I have a test page here and it does not pull the title, so almost there https://nicholas-mcdonough-9ycm.squarespace.com/home/blog 2. Thanks, It did work but using the same logic, why does it not work for the LinkedIn Button? I change it thinking the same problem existed.

Comment: I updated the codepen.io (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzdGLe )   you have to add an url on the li like you did for facebook and in c = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&,  remove "url=" because the parameters is allready in the var c.  hope it helps

Comment: A point of clarity: The objective is to able to share individual pages of a blog. This does not appear to change the url to correspond to the page being shared. In the case of Facebook, it does not pull the title and image of the page to be shared. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: no i dont understand sorry, you put the url that you want in html part in data-share-link or in javascript side you use window.location.href to get current page.

Comment: The whole point of having share buttons is to allow the blog post to be shared. To do so, one needs to be able to share the URL, image, and text. I need javascript side to do that. The code I have does not work. Im asking and needing help to understand why it does not work.